# Make a 'common' login.js include; with nightwatch.js tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, npm, nightwatch.js

When writing tests for my web app; I have to first simulate login before the rest of my tests can run and see inner pages. Right now I'm working on modulating the code, so that way I can just make an 'include' for the common function; such as my login. But as soon as I move the below code in a separate file, and call the include via `require` - it no longer runs as expected.

*ie.* the below logs in and allows my other functions, if, included in the same file. above my other inner screen functions.

```
// Login screen, create opportunity

this.LoginScreen = function(browser) {
        browser
                .url(Data.urls.home)
                .waitForElementVisible('#login', 2000, false)
                .click('#login')
                .waitForElementVisible('div.side-panel.open', 4000, false)
                .waitForElementVisible('input#email', 2000, false)
                .waitForElementVisible('input#password', 2000, false)
                .click('input#email')
                .pause(500)
                .setValue('input#email', Data.ProjMan.username)
                .click('input#password')
                .pause(500)
                .setValue('input#password', Data.ProjMan.password)
                .click('input#email') 
                .pause(500)
                .click('div.form.login-form .btn')
                .pause(5000)

        Errors.checkForErrors(browser);
};     

// Inner functions run after here, sequentially
```

But as soon as I move the above in a separate file, for instance; `Logins.js`, then call it at the top of the original test file with. (yes, correct path).

```
var Logins      = require("../../lib/Logins.js");
```

It just doesn't simulate the login anymore. Any thoughts? Should I remove the `this.LoginScreen` function wrapper, and call it differently to execute from the external file, or do I need to fire it from the original file again, aside from the external require path?

I have also tried wrapping '`module.exports = {`' around the login function from separate file, but still failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nightwatch allows you to run your Page object based tests i.e you can externalize your common test functions and use them in your regular tests. This can be achieved using '[page_objects_path](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#basic-settings)' property. I have added the common 'login' functionality and used it in sample 'single test' in the project [here](https://github.com/kannamaraj/nightwatch-browserstack/).

**Working**:

Place your common function in .js file and place it under a folder(ex: tests/pages/login.js) and pass the folder path in nighwatch config file as below:

```
 nightwatch_config = {
      src_folders : [ 'tests/single' ],
      page_objects_path: ['tests/pages'],
```

Below is an example of common login function (login.js):

```
var loginCommands = {

  login: function() {
    return this.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .verify.visible('@userName')
      .verify.visible('@password')
      .verify.visible('@submit')
      .setValue('@userName', 'Enter Github user name')
      .setValue('@password', 'Enter Github password')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000)

  }
};

 module.exports = {
      commands: [loginCommands],
        url: function() {
          return 'https://github.com/login';
        },
      elements: {
        userName: {
          selector: '//input[@name=\'login\']',
          locateStrategy: 'xpath'
        },
        password: {
          selector: '//input[@name=\'password\']',
          locateStrategy: 'xpath'
        },
        submit: {
          selector: '//input[@name=\'commit\']',
          locateStrategy: 'xpath'
        }
      }
    };
```

Now, in your regular test file, create an object for the common function as below and use it.

```
 module.exports = {
      'Github login Functionality' : function (browser) {

    //create an object for login
    var login = browser.page.login();
    //execute the login method from //tests/pages/login.js file
    login.navigate().login();

    //You can continue with your tests below:
    // Also, you can use similar Page objects to increase reusability
        browser
        .pause(3000)
          .end();
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is absolutly correct however I did struggle with how to supply login user details.

This is what I ended up using:

```
var loginCommands = {

    login: function() {
      return this.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
        .setValue("#email", "<some rnd email address>")
        .setValue('#password', "<some rnd password>")
        .click('button[type=submit]')
        .pause(1000)
    }
  };
  
  module.exports = {
    commands: [loginCommands],
      url: function() {
        return 'https://example.com/login';
      }
  };
```

This can be used in the same way as the accepted answer just posting for others who come searching.